# Step Function causes lambda's to time out

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have the following step function defined:

```
{
  "StartAt": "lambda_1",
  "States": {
    "lambda_1": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:lambda_1",
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "Lambda.ServiceException",
            "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
            "Lambda.SdkClientException"
          ],
          "IntervalSeconds": 2,
          "MaxAttempts": 6,
          "BackoffRate": 2
        }
      ],
      "Next": "lambda_2"
    },
    "lambda_2": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:lambda_2",
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "Lambda.ServiceException",
            "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
            "Lambda.SdkClientException"
          ],
          "IntervalSeconds": 2,
          "MaxAttempts": 6,
          "BackoffRate": 2
        }
      ],
      "Next": "Choice"
    },
    "Choice": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.status",
          "StringEquals": "Available",
          "Next": "lambda_3"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "Wait"
    },
    "lambda_3": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:lambda3",
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "Lambda.ServiceException",
            "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
            "Lambda.SdkClientException"
          ],
          "IntervalSeconds": 2,
          "MaxAttempts": 6,
          "BackoffRate": 2
        }
      ],
      "End": true
    },
    "Wait": {
      "Type": "Wait",
      "Seconds": 1800,
      "Next": "lambda_2"
    }
  }
}
```

But for some reason, any 1 of the 3 lambda's defined will continuously timeout for no reason that I cannot figure out. The lambda's work well run by themselves, and the VPC configurations seem to be working. I have increased the timeout period to 10-15 minutes and also increased the storage as well, but cannot figure out why these lambda's time out within this step function.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Does the step function have the necessary access to trigger the Lambdas?

Comment: @TrygviLaksafoss, yes I believe so... the weird thing is that the step function will work about 20% of the time, and the other 80% of the time fail from a "Lambda Unknown" error

Comment: the Lambda.Unkown error stems from an unhadled error in the lambdas. I see you don't have this error in the retry block meaning that it will not retry when hitting this error. I would however look into the Lambdas to find what could cause the timeout or out of memory.

Comment: That is a good idea, I will add it as a retry to see if that helps. Hmm what is weird is when I execute the lambda individually, they work fine.